# "Call to a member function mailsend() on null" in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP i try to create a form to send emails. I have a function mailsend(), but when i try to send a form I have an error "Call to a member function mailsend() on null". I can't see what am I doing wrong. Please, help.

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
            $data = $this->data;

            $errors=array();

            if(!$data['name']){$errors['name'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Namen ein';}
            if(!$data['email']){$errors['email'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail-Adresse ein';}
            if(!$data['title']){$errors['title'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Titel ein';}
            if(!$data['description']){$errors['description'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine Nachricht ein';}

            if(count($errors) > 0){
                //wystąpiły błędy
                $result = array('res'=>'no','list'=>$errors);
                $data['result'] = $result;
                $el['Contact'] = $data;
                //$this->vd($el);
                //$this->set('el',$el);
            }else{
                $result = array('res'=>'yes','list'=>'Vielen Dank für das Senden einer E-Mail');

                $txt = $data['name'].'<br>'.$data['description'];
                $subject = $data['title'];
                $from = $data['email'];

                $this->Helpers->mailsend($txt, $subject, $from);
                $data['result'] = $result;
                $this->Contact->save($data);

                $this->Session->setFlash('Nachricht gesendet');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'contact/'));
            }
        }
```

```
public function mailsend($txt='', $subject='', $from=''){

        $mail='xyz@gmail.com';
        $header = "From: Kogni-Fit <office@xyz.at>".PHP_EOL;
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL;
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8".PHP_EOL; 

        $message = '<html> 
                <head> 
                   <title>'.$subject.'</title> 
                </head>
                <body>
                   '.$txt.'<br><br>
                   '.$from.'
                </body>
        </html>';
        return mail($mail, $subject, $message, $header);
    }
```

Comment: Seems clear that `$this->Helpers` is null. Why do you think it would be non-null? You haven't said where your `mailsend` function is implemented.

Comment: So how can I call this function from controller? Only $this-> don't work either. Folder Helper is in folder View.

Comment: First of all, [helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/views/helpers.html) are for use in templates, not in controllers. Maybe you wanted to make a [component](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component)?

Comment: Thank You. I think the last advice was the point. I create a component with method mailsend() and I think it will be working. I still have a problem with send an email, but its problem in connection with server. I work on a local server. When I'll publish website it shoud be working. Thanks